# src/net.cpp | What does "nUnkBias" define/mean

Tags: connection

net.cpp for example:

// use an nUnkBias between 10 (no outgoing connections) and 90 (8 outgoing connections)
            CAddress addr = addrman.Select(10 + min(nOutbound,8)*10);

**What does this line of code exactly mean/do?**

Comment: F.Y.I.: this code has been removed (https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/5941) from bitcoin-core.

Comment: thx for info, found it